# Relation among Diameter and Radius in an Undirected Graph?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

we consider only graphs that are undirected. The **diameter** of a graph is the maximum, over all choices of vertices `s` and `t`, of the shortest-path distance between `s` and `t` . (Recall the shortest-path distance between `s` and `t` is the fewest number of edges in an `s-t`  path.) Next, for a vertex `s`, let `l(s)` denote the maximum, over all vertices `t`, of the shortest-path distance between `s` and `t`. The **radius** of a graph is the minimum of `l(s)` over all choices of the vertex `s`. 
with radius `r` and the diameter `d` which of the following is always hold? choose the best answer.

> 1) r >= d/2
>   2) r <= d

we know the (1) and (2) always hold and in any reference book that written. 
my challenge is this problem mentioned on Entrance Exam and just one of (1) or (2) should be true, the OP says choose the best answer and after the exam answer sheet wrote (1) is the best choice. How can verify me, why the (1) is better than (2).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of maths, not of programming.

Comment: On the contrary, (2) is "better" because (1) does not hold when negative edge lengths are allowed: for a triangle with edge lengths {3,-4,5}, d=1 and r=-1; here (2) is still valid but (1) is wrong.

Comment: would you please see http://stolzen.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/courses/coursera/Algorithms%20Design%20and%20Analysis%20Part%201/week4/week4_quiz_feedback.pdf   @EvgenyKluev the question (3). he wrote two of them is correct. but my professor in another quiz wrote which better select (1)

Comment: he say always hold for every undirected graph :) how you reach that (1) is wrong for negative edge !?!!!?!!?!?!!? @EvgenyKluev

Comment: @Evgeny Kluev, this is incorrect.  Diameter is defined as the maximum eccentricity and radius is defined as the minimum eccentricity.  In the example you outline, for every node, n, in your triangle, the negative edge weight will not be included in the eccentricity of n.

Answer (score 3):

They both are indeed True.
Don't let an exam with ambiguous questions weaken your concepts.

Well as for the Proof:

First of all 2nd inequality is quite trivial (from the definition itself)

Now the 1st one

> d <= 2*r

Let z be a central vertex, then:

```
e(z)=r
```

Now,

```
diameter = d(x,y)       [d(x,y) denotes distance between some vertex x & y]

d(x,y) <= d(x,z) + d(z,y)

d(x,y) <= d(z,x) + d(z,y)

d(x,y) <= e(z) + e(z)       [this can be an upper bound as e(z)>=d(z,u) for all u]

diameter <= 2*r
```

Answer (score 2):

They both hold.

2) should be clear.

1) holds using the triangle inequality.  We can use this property because distances on graphs are a metric (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29).  Using Let d(x, z) = diameter(G) and let y be a center of G (i.e. there exists a vertex v in G such that d(y, v) = radius(G)).  Because d(y, v) = radius(G) and d(y, v) = d(v, y), we know that d(v, z) <= radius(G).  Then we have that diameter(G) = d(x, z) <= d(y, v) + d(v, z) <= 2*radius(G).

Comment: please see comments that  for a triangle with edge lengths {3,-4,5}, d=1 and r=-1; here (2) is still valid but (1) is wrong

Comment: you means if we consider negative edges, again two of them is correct?

Comment: Why d(v,z)<=radius(G) ?

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi As we already know, y is center of G. It means radius is d(y,v)=radius(G). Besides, longest path has been rooted from y is radius.

Comment: @Arman d(v, z) has nothing to do with node y, d(y, v) is the longest path that is rooted from y. d(v, z) can be the longest path that is rooted from v, so d(v, z) is the eccentricity of node v, and a radius is the minimum of all eccentricities. Thus d(v, z) can be longer than d(y, v). Could you explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 2):

The OP defined the shortest-path distance between s and t as "the fewest number of edges in an s-t path".  This makes things simpler.

We may write the definitions in terms of some pseudocode:

```
def dist(s, t):
    return min([len(path)-1 for path starts with s and ends with t])

r = min([max([dist(s, t) for t in V]) for s in V])
d = max([max([dist(s, t) for t in V]) for s in V])
```

where `V` is the set of all vertexes.

Now (2) is obviously true.  The definition itself tells this: `max always >= min`.

(1) is slightly less obvious.  It requires at least a few steps to prove.

Suppose `d = dist(A, B)`, and `r = dist(C, D)`, we have

```
dist(C, A) + dist(C, B) >= dist(A, B),
```

otherwise the length of path `A-C-B` would be smaller than `dist(A, B)`.

From the definition of `r`, we know that

```
dist(C, D) >= dist(C, A)
dist(C, D) >= dist(C, B)
```

Hence `2 * dist(C, D) >= dist(A, B)`, i.e., `2 * r >= d`.

So which one is better?  This depends on how you define "better".  If we consider something non-trivially correct (or not so obvious) to be better than something trivially correct, then we may agree that (1) is better than (2).